# Extremely slow UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

I noticed that a script of mine became very slow, then I narrowed down to the problem: it was an Update query. The weird thing is that the SELECT query is very fast. The table has about 600,000 entries. And yes, id is UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY. Here are some examples:

```
SELECT * FROM `tmp_pages_data` WHERE id = 19080 LIMIT 0 , 30

Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)
```

And now the update query:

```
UPDATE tmp_pages_data SET page_status = 1 WHERE id = 19080

1 row(s) affected. ( Query took 24.5968 sec )
```

As you can see, the select is very fast, but the update is veery slow. How is this possible?

Comment: Please add the structure of your schema, and especially the indexes. Write the indexes size and engine type as well

Comment: Ok, here is how the table looks like: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_pages_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_normal` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=658002 ;

Comment: Indexes: PRIMARY (BTREE) unique: Yes packed:No Field:id Cardinality: 658001 Collation:A Null: No; Index: url (BTREE) unique:No packed:No Field:url Cardinality:658001 Collation:A Null:YES

Comment: Space usage: Data  66,687.8  KiB
Index  52,885.0  KiB
Total  116.8  MiB

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very weird. Only thing I can think of is that `tmp_pages_data` table is locked by other transaction, or row with `id = 19080` is locked by other transaction.

The other (improbable thing) is that you have an index on `page_status` that needs to be updated on the `UPDATE` sentence, and that part is taking a lot of time to execute.

Comment: Actually, I DID have an index on page_status, but removed it

Comment: Hm... no, that's not the reason. I thought that maybe the index wasn't "properly" removed, but that's not the case. I have made a test: UPDATE tmp_pages_data SET cat_id = 1 WHERE id = 19080 -> 1 row(s) affected. ( Query took 4.7825 sec ) So still a lot of time (and there is no index on cat_id and never was one)

Answer (score -2):

Ok, done!

I had to restart Apache, now it works great (actually I have rebooted Ubuntu)!

```
UPDATE tmp_pages_data SET page_status =1 WHERE id =19080

1 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0004 sec )
```

Thanks everyone for your suggestions :)